# MySQL on duplicate key update add value from query

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mariadb

I want to:

- first summarize inventory data from two tables.
- And when I summarize second table and insert data to summarized table.
- On duplicate key situation, I want to add-up 2 inventory.

Thank you for your help!

```
delete from 02_inventory.tempinvsummary;

insert into 02_inventory.tempinvsummary 
(select pn,
sum(if(tp='Coil',no,0)) as 'coil',
sum(if(tp='Blank',no,0)) as 'blank', 
sum(if(tp='Press',no,0)) as 'press',
sum(if(tp='Assy',no,0)) as 'assy' ,
sum(if(tp='Robot',no,0)) as 'robot'
from inventory  
group by pn);

insert into 02_inventory.tempinvsummary 
(select pn,
sum(if(tp='Coil',no,0)) as 'suplcoil',
sum(if(tp='Blank',no,0)) as 'suplblank', 
sum(if(tp='Press',no,0)) as 'suplpress',
sum(if(tp='Assy',no,0)) as 'suplassy' ,
sum(if(tp='Robot',no,0)) as 'suplrobot'
from suplinventory
group by pn)
on duplicate key update

'====================
'prbly need codes here
coil=coil+suplcoil ????
'====================    
select * from 00_masterdata.itemmaster, 02_inventory.tempinvsummary
where 00_masterdata.itemmaster.pn= 02_inventory.tempinvsummary.pn;
```

Comment: Table definitions for 02_inventory.tempinvsummary,inventory ,suplinventory and sample data added as text to the question or a sql fiddle would be nice. Also you seem to be netting the results of the 2 queries so do you have a query which does that?

Comment: well I have 2 tables of row data (inventory, suplinventory) with same structure pn(partnumber), tp(product type), no(stock amount) which means item stock by boxes and pallets. each row data has 1 box of item. the query i am trying to write is to 1. summarize each tables' data and put them together into tempinvsummary. then 2. when pn(part number) is duplicated add up the numbers of item stock. and then join the stock info with itemmaster table to show current stocks in factory and its properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tables look a bit like this

```
drop table if exists tempinvsummary, inventory, suplinventory;

create table tempinvsummary (pn int primary key, col1 int);
create table inventory (pn int , col1 int);
create table suplinventory (pn int , col1 int);

insert into tempinvsummary values (1,null),(2,null);

insert into inventory values (1,10),(1,10),(3,10);
insert into suplinventory values (2,10);
```

You could union and summarize the 2 tables and then test and update on duplicate like this

```
insert into tempinvsummary (pn,col1)
select  pn,
        sum(case when src = 'i' then col1 else 0 end) + sum(case when src ='s' then col1 else 0 end) netcol1
from
(
select 'i' as src,i.pn,i.col1 from inventory i
union all
select 's' as src,s.pn,s.col1 from suplinventory s
) s
group by pn
on duplicate key
update col1 = values(col1);
```

Result

```
+----+------+
| pn | col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 |   20 |
|  2 |   10 |
|  3 |   10 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I'm not convinced you need a temporary table if you only need it to join it to 00_masterdata.itemmaster

for example

```
select  masterdata.username,pn,netcol1
from    users as masterdata
join
(
select  pn,
        sum(case when src = 'i' then col1 else 0 end) + sum(case when src ='s' then col1 else 0 end) netcol1
from
(
select 'i' as src,i.pn,i.col1 from inventory i
union all
select 's' as src,s.pn,s.col1 from suplinventory s
) s
group by pn

) a
on a.pn = masterdata.id;
```

Where I am using a convenient table called users in my db to illustrate the point

result

```
+----------+------+---------+
| username | pn   | netcol1 |
+----------+------+---------+
| John     |    1 |      20 |
| Jane     |    2 |      10 |
| Ali      |    3 |      10 |
+----------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Your calculation would be much more simply written as:          `sum(col1) as netcol1`.